# My Current Location Shows a Different Location, Google Maps - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, swiftui

I have implemented `Google Maps` but my `Current Location` is always `USA`. I am testing it on `REAL device` and i have `location permissions` added in `info.plist`. `Google API key` is also implemented in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate`.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>By accessing your location, this app can help you navigate between different locations.</string>
```

Here is my code. I'm following this tutorial by raywenderlich.com.  https://www.raywenderlich.com/7363101-google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial-getting-started I have downloaded the material of this tutorial, used my API Key but still my current location is always USA. Tested on multiple real devices.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var mapView : GMSMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      locationManager.delegate = self
      self.mapView.delegate = self
    } else {
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
  }
}
```

CLLocationManagerDelegate:-

```
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else { return }
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
  }
  
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.first else { return }
   
  // the coordinates i get here are always from some city in USA.
 mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(
      target: location.coordinate,
      zoom: 15,
      bearing: 0,
      viewingAngle: 0)
    }
  
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error: \(error)")
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Check the location authorization status when the `view` appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the settings below as screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much bro @zeytin. My core location was USA :| , How strange, it never happened to me for MapKit. Anyways thanks alot bro :D